# Cannot convert string to my custom data type Category

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have Item class and Category class. Item class has a reference to the Category class.

Item Class is as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMS")
public class Item {

@OneToOne
private Category category;
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Category Class is as follows.

```
package com.easypos.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_REMARK", nullable = true)
    private String categoryDescription;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName.trim();
    }

    public String getCategoryDescription() {
        return categoryDescription;
    }

    public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
        this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.categoryName;
    }



}
```

My controller methods are as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String create(Model model) {
        item = new Item();
        model.addAttribute("title", "Add Item");
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("suppliers", supplierService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute(item);
        return "item/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePorduct(Model model, @ModelAttribute("item") @Valid Item item, BindingResult result,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        itemValidator.validate(item, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Add Item");
            model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("suppliers", supplierService.findAll());
            return "item/create";
        }
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Item successfully saved.");
        itemService.saveitem(item);
        return "redirect:/item/";
    }
```

In My `Jsp` file i have used the following code to show the categories in a select box.

has-error  ">
                                Category

`<div class="col-sm-9">
                                <sf:select path="category" cssClass="form-control">
                                   <sf:options items='${categories}' itemValue='id'/>
                                </sf:select>
                                <p><sf:errors path="category" /></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>`

In My `Jsp` file when I submit the form I get the error which says "no matching editors or conversion strategy found" - the full error log is as follows:

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.easypos.models.Category] for property category; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.easypos.models.Category] for property category: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: I don't about such frameworks; but if you expect to convert a String into a Category ... maybe the Category class needs at least a constructor that takes a string?

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` wouldn't help you in this case. You'll be needing a PropertyEditor or Formatter or Converter registered for converting string data to Category that you are sending to server. I'd need to see how does your JSP file look before giving you any code example but [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) should be a good place to start.

Comment: <sf:select path="category" cssClass="form-control">
         <sf:options items='${categories}' itemValue='id'/></sf:select>
      <p><sf:errors path="category" /></p>

Answer (score 0):

Here ITEM table is redundant. Because Item class contains only one attribute and it's one-to-one relation. So you should avoid this entity class. One more thing, every entity class should have an primary key with @Id annotation.

Clearly noticeable that Item class takes Category type attribute and from your jsp form there has no Category type attribute. For an example:

```
<form action="action_url" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a"/>
    <input type="text" name="b"/>
    <input type="text" name="c"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

For this jsp form your entity/model class should like ,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "C_1")
    private String a;

    @Column(name = "C_2")
    private String b;

    @Column(name = "C_2")
    private String c;

    ...Getter and Setter here....
}
```

It's have to make sure that form element name and model attributes name are  same if you want to auto bind them. But in your jsp page there have no element named "category" and you can't create this type of form element cause Category is a user defined class and html does not know this type of element. I hope you got the point.

You should Use Category object to bind the elements.
Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePorduct(Model model, @ModelAttribute("category") Category category,  BindingResult result) {
--other logic here--
}
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make one thing clear. If you want to bind nested object fields, you have to set the 'name' attribute of your html element like name="object.field"
Here you're trying to bind the value of your select element (which is String) to the category field (that's is type Category) in your Item class. This won't work.

try

```
path = "category.categoryName"
```

and see if it works.

Anyways, You sould have a primary key on Item Entity.